# Catching exceptions in setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

Quick question, if I do this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    try {
        riskyFunc();
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}, 1000);
```

In my head I am thinking that if anything goes wrong in `riskyFunc()`, it will be caught. Is this true? There are also some async calls I know of for sure inside `riskyFunc()`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it will be caught: but only when the callback is executed.  That is, if `riskyFunc` throws an exception, it won't be caught in your example until the callback executes in one second.

You've probably heard before that you have to be careful with exceptions when using asynchronous methods, and the usual mistake people make is this:

```
try {
    setInterval(function() {
        riskyFunc();
    }, 1000);
} catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

They are confused when `riskyFunc` throws an exception and it isn't caught.  It isn't caught because the exception doesn't happen when you call `setInterval`; it happens when `setInterval` invokes the anonymous function sometime in the future, which is outside of the context of the original try/catch block.  You are doing it the correct way: by doing the exception handling inside the callback.

If `riskyFunc` in turn invokes asynchronous calls, those too have to handle exceptions in this manner.  For example:

```
function riskyFunc() {
    // do some stuff
    asyncFn(function(){
        throw new Error('argh');
    }
}
```

That exception will not get caught in the try/catch block inside your `setInterval` call.  You'll have to keep applying the pattern on down:

```
function riskyFunc() {
    // do some stuff
    asyncFn(function() {
        try {
            // work that may throw exception
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the exception to "propagate up", you'll have to use promises, or some other way to indicate success/failure.  Here's a common method, by using a "done" callback that is capable of reporting an error:

```
function riskyFunc(done) {
    // do some stuff
    asyncFn(function() {
        try {
            // do some more risky work
            done(null, 'all done!');
        } catch(e) {
            done(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call that in your `setTimeout` and take into account possible asynchronous failures:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    try {
        riskyFunc(function(err, msg) {
            // this will cover any asynchronous errors generated by
            // riskyFunc
            if(err) return console.error(err);
            console.log(msg);
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // riskyFunc threw an exception (not something it
        // invoked asynchronously)
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`setInterval` already puts the block in an asynchronous block. And exceptions can't be caught in out-of-sync. The right pattern is to use a Promise object, and call a `fail()` operation if something goes wrong. For this example, I'm using jQuery's `Deferred` object, but any promise library has similar usage:

```
var promise = $.Deferred();

setInterval(function () {
    try{
       riskyFunc();
    } catch (e) {
       promise.reject(e);
    }
    promise.resolve(/* some data */);
}, 1000);

promise
    .done(function (data) { /* Handled resolve data */ })
    .fail(function (error) { /* Handle error */ });
```

Note that since you're using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` that this will be called every second unless you clear the timeout, so if you need to call the function multiple times in parallel, you might want an array of promises.

Comment: Found this useful, would you mind explaining a bit on what you mean by  exceptions can't be caught in out-of-sync.

Answer (score 3):

If riskyFunc is

```
function() {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        throw "mistake";
    });
}
```

your catch block will not catch. I believe this is the case you are worried about, and all you can do is set global exception handlers, or hope for the best. (No, promises will not catch this. They are not magic.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ethan Brown for the detailed explanation. I think your last setTimeout is missing the timer - see below

```
setTimeout(function() {
    try {
        riskyFunc(function(err, msg) {
            // this will cover any asynchronous errors generated by
            // riskyFunc
            if(err) return console.error(err);
            console.log(msg);
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // riskyFunc threw an exception (not something it
        // invoked asynchronously)
        console.error(e);
    }
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one of way by using `promise.race` and using promise. Not sure this proper way but will help to catch error in catch block without adding try and catch inside setTimeout specifically

```
try {
  await Promise.race([
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeoutObj = setTimeout(() => {
        reject('Threshold memory exceeded')
      }, 1000);
    })
  ]);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  // Do something
}
```