# Catching exceptions thrown from inside the setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, try-catch

What is the best way to catch the error thrown from inside the `setInterval`? Currently from the code below, on throwing the exception, the control does not reach `catch`.

```
    try {

        timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (moment().diff(lastProcessTime, 'minute') >= 2) {
                // Taking too long!
                clearInterval(timer);
                throw new Error({ code: -1, message: `Taking too long to response:: ${urls[0]}` });
            }
        }, 1000);


        await c.downloadAndSaveDataFromRssUrls(configs, urls);
        clearInterval(timer);
        return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (err) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log(err);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching exceptions in setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515558/catching-exceptions-in-setinterval)

Comment: You don't catch exceptions from asynchronous callbacks. You don't use `setInterval` for timeouts. You don't use `setInterval` with promises. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37120240/1048572) for how to timeout your `downloadAndSaveDataFromRssUrls` call.

Comment: @Bergi That was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `try catch` inside the `setInterval`
 :

```js
function greet() {
  let i = setInterval(() => {
    try {
      if (Math.random() * 100 > 5) {
        clearInterval(i);
        throw new Error("Number is greater than 5");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Hello')
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

greet();
```

Comment: This won't help my case. Update the code in question.

Comment: Nothing has changed, you can still add a `try catch` inside your `setInterval`.

Comment: I want to throw an exception from setInterval and return from the outer try catch. Is that possible?

Comment: No, since `setInterval` is asynchronous.